# Keep output and input from alternating?

Tags: c++

I am *very* new to coding, and have been practicing with some easy problems at codeforces.com.  I was working on [this problem](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/71/A), but it seemed to be asking for the input (all at once) yielding the output (all at once).  I can only figure out how to get one output at a time.

Here are the basic instructions for the problem:

> ## Input
>
> The first line contains an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100). Each of the following n lines contains one word. All the words consist of lowercase Latin letters and possess the lengths of from 1 to 100 characters.
>
> ## Output
>
> Print n lines. The i-th line should contain the result of replacing of the i-th word from the input data.
>
> ## Examples
>
> **input**
>
> 4
>
> word
>
> localization
>
> internationalization
>
> pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
>
> **output**
>
> word
>
> l10n
>
> i18n
>
> p43s

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void wordToNumbers(string word){
    int midLetters = word.length();
    char firstLetter = word.front();
    char lastLetter = word.back();
    cout <<firstLetter <<(midLetters-2) <<lastLetter <<endl;
}

int main(){
    string wordInput;
    string firstNum;

    getline(cin,firstNum);

    int i = stoi(firstNum);

    for(i>=1; i--;){
        getline(cin,wordInput);

        if (wordInput.length() > 10){
            wordToNumbers(wordInput);
        } else {
            cout <<wordInput <<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you summarise the problem in the question body please? Links tend to break.

Comment: I think it is still okay to print to std::out one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's perfectly fine to read and print output for the lines one by one.

Exactly your solution accepted: http://codeforces.com/contest/71/submission/16659519

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a beginner in c++. My idea would be to save every line first in a buffer and then write everything to std::cout.

I use a std::vector as the buffer, cause IMO it is simple to understand and very useful in many cases. Basically it is a better array. You can read more about std::vector [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//for use of std::vector container
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void wordToNumbers(string word){
    int midLetters = word.length();
    char firstLetter = word.front();
    char lastLetter = word.back();
    cout <<firstLetter <<(midLetters-2) <<lastLetter <<endl;
}

int main(){
    string wordInput;
    string firstNum;

    //container for buffering all our strings
    vector<string> bufferStrings;

    getline(cin,firstNum);

    int i = stoi(firstNum);

    //read line by line and save every line in our buffer-container
    for(i>=1; i--;){
        getline(cin,wordInput);
        //append the new string to our buffer
        bufferStrings.push_back(wordInput);
    }

    //now iterate through the buffer and write everything to cout
    for(int index = 0; index < bufferStrings.size(); ++index) {
        if (bufferStrings[index].length() > 10){
            wordToNumbers(bufferStrings[index]);
        } else {
            cout <<bufferStrings[index] <<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Probably this is not the best or most beautiful solution, but it should be easy to understand :)